# Create checkerboard pattern with Python (Canvas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter's canvas and I'd like to create a checkered black and white pattern with it but I'm stuck on how I'd do it. Wondering if anyone would be able to help me? Thanks!

Comment: you can draw rectangles on canvas - [canvas.create_rectange(...)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) - or you could use `Labels` or `Buttons` with layout manager `grid()` in `Frame` which you can put on canvas or directly in window. Eventually load image with checkerboard and display it on `canvas` (or in `Label/Button`)

Comment: @furas I'd like to do it in a for loop of some kind really.

Comment: so use `for`-loop. What is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [canvas.create_rectange()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_rectangle-method) to draw rectangles on `Canvas`

Using two `for`-loops and changing color in every loop you can get

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SIZE = 20

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

color = 'white'

for y in range(8):

    for x in range(8):
        x1 = x*SIZE
        y1 = y*SIZE
        x2 = x1 + SIZE
        y2 = y1 + SIZE
        canvas.create_rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=color)
        if color == 'white':
            color = 'black'
        else:    
            color = 'white'

    if color == 'white':
        color = 'black'
    else:    
        color = 'white'

root.mainloop()
```